# How to monitor PooledConnectionFactory (via JMX?)

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I have a client app that is consuming from a queue in an activemq cluster.  The app is running in tomcat 7 and uses camel (v2.10.3) and spring 3.1.2.  I use a PooledConnectionFactory to connect.

Everything works for a while (sometimes days), but then all of the connections go away in the pool (the activemq broker web console shows no consumers.  I figured it was the [idletimeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994367/activemqs-messages-being-redelivered-pooledconnectionfactory-misconfig-suspect), but adding the suggested config didn't help.  I also upgraded to activemq-pool-5.10.0.jar, but also no luck.

SO, I'm trying to find out what is going on and was hoping to use JMX, but I can not find any related mbeans (via jconsole) that the pool registers.  Is there a way to monitor/control the pool via JMX (or another/better way)?

My config fyi:

```
  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMWSslConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="failover://ssl://...."/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
      <property name="idleTimeout" value="0"/>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it sounds, I don't see any other option other than to turn on TRACE level logging for that class. Check out the logs of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15994367/3950710).

Comment: Thanks, that's the idle timeout issue to which I refer - unfortunately the idletimeout fix did not help.  I have been tracing for a few days now and nothing of interest is in the logs - although the issue has not happened yet, so hopefully when it does I will see something of interest.  Of note for anyone else tracing, class org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.activemq/activemq-pool/5.10.0/org/apache/activemq/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.java) uses the logger for org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.